# Dit-on « la langue créole haïtien » ou « la langue créole haïtienne » ?

Tags: genre

Selon *Google Search*, ce serait le premier :

[image: Google Search : "langue créole haïtien" vs "langue créole haïtienne"]

Selon, *Google Ngram Viewer*, par contre, ce serait le deuxième :

[image: Google Ngram Viewer : "langue créole haïtien" & "langue créole haïtienne"]

Deuxièmement, si c'est le premier, pourquoi, alors qu'on dit bien « la langue français**e** » et « la langue allemand**e** » ?

Answer (score 8):

On dit ***le créole haïtien*** car *créole* est un substantif masculin. On ne peut pas dire *la créole haïtienne* sauf si on sous-entend un substantif comme femme, recette, voire langue.

En revanche, ***la langue créole haïtienne*** est grammatical car *créole* est alors un adjectif.

Si, et c'est quand même beaucoup plus rare, on continue à le considérer comme un substantif, *la langue créole haïtien* peut se comprendre comme *la langue (nommée) créole haïtien*, c'est à dire ***la langue « créole haïtien »*** comme on dirait *la langue « français québécois »*. Il faut marquer une petite pause après langue pour que ça n'écorche pas les oreilles car *créole* et *français* ont des formes féminines, mais si on prend une langue dont le nom n'est pas aussi un adjectif, la pause n'est plus nécessaire:

> *Il l’a esquissé d’une main mal assurée, poursuit Christian Robin, mais son goût de l’anticipation le tiendra jusqu’à la fin de sa vie. Dans ce texte, il parle de Libreville au Congo et **de la langue espéranto**, appelée à s’imposer à la planète​.* [Ouest-France](https://www.ouest-france.fr/pays-de-la-loire/nantes-44000/des-recits-retrouves-de-jules-verne-093aba4e-4b1a-11ed-a299-c34310d448f8)

Une prédiction de Jules Verne qui ne s'est pas réalisée...